# Need help with declarative sentence

Tags: узус

How would you translate this sentence: "Nikita Sergeyevich Mikhalkov the director of Burnt by the Sun"

I thought it would be:
 " <<Утомленные солнцем>> директора - Никита Сергеевич Михалов "

Or is it:
 "Директор  <<Утомленных солнц>> - Никита Сергеевич Михалов "

Большое спасибо!!

Comment: You missed the verb and the correct translation of the word "director".

Comment: @Abakan According to English-Russian dictionary by Kenneth Katzner, the translation for "director" is "директор" and the singular genitive declension is "директора"

What am I missing here?

Comment: @Abakan oh whoops it would be "режиссёр"  hahaha I need glasses

Comment: Well, you deleted the verb and it is not a sentence now...

Comment: `Директор <<Утомленных солнц>>` literally means `the director of Burnt Suns`. To say `the director of Burnt by the Sun` you have to use correct case: `Директор <<Утомленных солнцем>>`

Answer (score 4):

It's the second one, well, almost

> Режиссёр фильма "Утомлённые солнцем" Никита Сергеевич Михалков

The version with dash necessitates the verb **`to be`** in the English sentence

> Nikita Sergeyevich Mikhalkov **IS** the director of "Burnt by the Sun"

for it to be the first one however (with correct declension of the name as `Никиты Сергеевича Михалкова`) the English sentence must look like

> "Burnt by the Sun" by the director Nikita Sergeyevich Mikhalkov

Comment: It's something like 'Winnie the Pooh' :).

Answer (score 2):

Depending of the surrounding context (if any) it should be either

> Режиссёр фильма "Утомлённые солнцем" Никита Сергеевич Михалков.

or

> Никита Сергеевич Михалков, режиссёр фильма "Утомлённые солнцем".